# To simplify the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\left\{\,r_{1}t+r_{2}\bigm| r_{1},r_{2} \in \mathbb{R}, t\in [0,1]\text{ and } {\sup_{s\in [0,1]} \left |r_{1}s + r_{2}  \right | \leq  1}\,\right\}$$
is there a way to write this set in a more simplified form?

Note that since the values of r can take negative, then substituting the values of t directly will not give he supremum.

Comment: Your set is syntactically malformed. The supremum is a real number but you are using it as a boolean.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. there was a typo

Comment: It's still malformed. You have an undefined variable $t$ on the left, because the $t$ on the right is only meaningful inside the expression under the $\sup$.

Comment: Sorry. I changed again. Hope this is correct

Comment: Now the set seems to be simply the closed interval $[-1,1]$ -- given $x\in[-1,1]$, it is a member of your set by setting $r_1=0$, $r_2=x$, and $t=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This set, say $X$, coincides with the interval $[-1,1]$. Obviously, by definition you have $X \subseteq [-1,1]$.

On the other hand, consider $r_1=2$ and $r_2=-1$. You can easily check that
$\sup_{s \in [0,1]} |2s-1| = 1$ and for all $x \in [-1,1]$ you have
$$x= 2 \left( \frac{x+1}{2}\right)-1 \in X$$
since $\frac{x+1}{2} \in [0,1]$. So you have the opposite inclusion $[-1,1] \subseteq X$.